How to handle Multiple SP on the same server pointing to the same IDP Azure AD?
I have two SP URLS  on the same server called,
SP1 : hro1.test.com
SP2: hro2.test.com
I have created two SP meta data and shared to AD later I have got two IDP from them and I configured two SP and IDP metadata from application side .
I have noticed that IDP that shared contained the same entity ID for both IDP meta data files .
entityID="https://sts.windows.net/xx ,,,xx xx/ but certificate and others are different.
after all the configuration I was able to connect SP1 with out any issue but SP2 URL keeps loading and I am getting the issue like** signature verification failed** .
Is there any possibility that we work with multiple SP's can point to single IDP entity ID for same server .
We actually suggested to give a single URL, but client want to use TWO SP URL to connect application .

Could you include more details like what scope you used and include code, errors if any by editing your question?
